# Curl returning intermittent "Failed connect - no error"

Tags: php, iis, curl

We have two applications on non-internet-facing servers within our corporate network. One application (client app) gets its data from the other (server app) via an API.

The client app uses the PHP library Jyggen\Curl to make calls to the API. On Friday, users started to report errors with the client app. When I checked the error logs, I could see that the Curl requests were intermittently failing with the error:

> Failed connect to server-app:80; no error

I was able to reproduce this by clicking around different pages in client app myself - eventually an API call would fail and the PHP lib would throw an exception. The error continued today and I was also able to reproduce it from the command line using curl.exe - I had to execute the command 10-15 times before I could get the error but it happened eventually.

The server app is also accessed directly by users in their browser (as well as by API) and we have had no problems there.

The Curl errors appear to be happening during the busiest period of the day (9am - 3pm UK time) in terms of use of the client app. Both apps run on IIS and have sufficient max concurrent users allowed for.

My two theories at the moment are:

1. Network issue - corporate IT can't see anything wrong however
2. Curl issue - is there something I'm not aware of regarding how many Curl requests can be made at any one time? Our number of users has been steadily increasing over the last few months so perhaps we have only just hit the tipping point where it's starting to cause issues? We are not using curl_multi, if that's relevant.

Any tips / ideas to check out next would be appreciated.

**Update**

I managed to reproduce the error this morning in my browser. I checked the IIS logs and I was the only person to be using the client app at that time (no one else had used it for more than 10 minutes). I am therefore minded to suggest that traffic on the client app is not a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(why do people insist on wrapping perfectly sensible APIs up in over-complicated OO?)

This is not really a programming question - it's about fault finding and most likely some infrastructure related issue.

If the client is failing to connect, then either the conection is being rejected or it is timing out. You should have enough information to determine which applies here.

If the connection is being rejected, then there won't be a significant delay. You need to go look at what is rejecting the connection (in the absence of a proxy or an IPS, that would be the IIS instance) and find the reason why.

If the connection is timing out, then the issue may be dropped packets on the network, or an issue on the remote server. Increasing the connection timeout will help for the latter. Start collecting the time it takes for the client to connect and see if there is any pattern (check for correlations with other events such as backups). If there isn't any noticeable pattern/increasing the timneout doesn't help then it's a packet loss issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was just able to reproduce the error on the command line with curl in verbose mode. It says Trying <IP>..., then after 10-15 seconds "Timed out" before giving the "Failed connect; no error" message. I am able to get the same result when trying to connect to other network locations so am trying to work with our network team.

Comment: Turned out to be a network firewall setting limiting the number of connections.